# In Django ORM, wildcard \b does not work (Postgres database)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

All other wildcards work correctly but for example when I want to use `"\bsome\b"` pattern, it can't find any result however, there are many rows in the database that have a word "some" inside them.

Other wild cards like `., +, *, \w` and ... work properly.

Any idea on what is the problem?

Code:

```
regex_pattern = r"\bsome\b"
result = tweets.filter(text__regex=regex_pattern)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\b` is not the same "boundary" metacharacter in Postgres (SQL) regexps it is in Python regexps; see [here for the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ESCAPE-SEQUENCES). (It's just backspace, like in regular strings.)

Instead, you'll probably want `\y`:

> `\y`: matches only at the beginning or end of a word

Comment: Thanks. One note is that `re.compile()` will consider `\y` as invalid regular expression if we want to validate our regular expression.

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to replace those if you want to use `re.compile()` for validation.